# Python find out contents of compiled module?

Tags: python, module, compiled, pyd

So have this Python .pyd module (C++), so I can't just open it in a text editor to find out what it contains. So how can I? I just want to know the function names inside it.

Answer (score 12):

Python have full reflection.

You can do the following (for a modulename.pyd)

```
 python
 >>> import modulename as mtmp
 >>> dir(mtmp)
 >>> help(mtmp)
```

**EDIT** : Add help command as propose by Mike Graham

Comment: (+1) Was about to suggest exactly the same thing.

Comment: Note that `help` is more useful than `dir`.